# biblatex, punctuation, and empty field

Tags: biblatex

I have a minor issue with biblatex and punctuation, when a field, say author,  may be empty. I would like to insert a comma instead that a period, when author is defined, but I fail to do so without to insert a comma even when author is empty.

So I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[american,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=mario-standard,defernumbers=true,sorting=ynt,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{min.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent 
\cite{*}

\defbibnote{A}{Group A}
\defbibnote{B}{Group B}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={A-}]
\printbibliography[prenote={A}, keyword=A] 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix={B-}]
\printbibliography[prenote={B}, keyword=B] 
\end{document}
```

min.bib file is

```
@Book{AAA,
%author = {NO Author},
label = {MM},
title = {aaa},
publisher = {book pub},
location = {myTown},
year = {2020},
 keywords = {A}
}

@Book{BBB,
author = {mario myself},
title = {bbb},
publisher = {book pub},
location = {myTown},
year = {2020},
 keywords = {B}
}
```

I use a custom .bbx file, where `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` is defined as:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \iffieldundef{note}{
    \newunit\newblock}{
    \printfield{note}
    }
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\subtitlepunct\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

The question is: how to hack `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` to get a comma after the author just in case author is defined. Thks.

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}` should be enough.

Comment: It seems it works. Thanks.  How/where do I renew the command just for the Book case?

Comment: Do you really want that? That would make things a tad inconsistent. Two possible solutions: `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\ifentrytype{book}{\addcomma\space}{\newunitpunct}}`. Or you change the `\setunit{\labelnamepunct}` in the `@book` driver to `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` has its punctuation tracker to make sure not to print punctuation when it is not needed (for example, if a field is missing/empty). You can read up on the punctuation tracker in §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* and §4.7 *Punctuation and Spacing* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

For this specific issue the punctuation lives in a dedicated macro, so

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Should be enough.

You can restrict this change to `@book` only with

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\addcomma‌​\space}
    {\newunitpunc‌​t}}
```

or by changing the line `\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock` in `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` to

```
\setunit{\addcomma‌​\space}\newblock
```

Comment: Can you explain why you chose `\space` and not `\addspace`?

Comment: Ok, I am a old  newbie: where do I learn about the punctuation tracker? Anyway, I got what I needed. Thks

Comment: @StrongBad Good question! `\addcomma‌​\space` is a common `biblatex` idiom. Essentially `\add<punct or space>` removes preceding space, does some bookkeeping and prints `<punct or space>`. If we use `\add<punct>` that already removes preceding space and does bookkeeping so that an `\addspace` after that would not add anything useful (since it comes after `\add<punct>` we can be sure no unwanted space was introduced), so we can resort to the simpler `\addcomma\space`. If it appears alone `\addspace` is preferred over `\space`, but in combination with other `\add<punct>` it might not be needed.

Comment: @mario I updated the answer with two references.